# Ubuntu asks for password several time when logging in

Tags: login, password

When ever I log into my machine (Lenovo Laptop) Ubuntu (Natty running Unity) ask for the keyring password several times (4-5) why does it do that and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Does it keep asking even if you get the password right?

Comment: When I had set up 'Log in Automatically' in Ubuntu 10.04, I used to have this issue. If I enter the right password it used to disappear or even clicking cancel made it disappear. Minimizing it also helps!

Comment: Yes it does keep asking after giving the correct password. I suspect those are different events who are calling this. I'll try to wait a little bit and then cancel the password next time and I'll see what happen

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like a problem with the Gnome keyring. I suggest ***backing up*** your `~/.gnome2/keyrings` directory and then try removing it to see if that helps. Of course, when you reenter your passwords for Evolution or a wireless network, it will ask you to create a password for your newly created keyring (picture shown below). Make sure that password is the same as your login password.

[image: Keyring]

Also, if you connect to a wireless network and you log in automatically, make sure you select "Available to all users" in your wireless settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably whatever agent is supposed to be handling storing that is not running in your session and it can't remember from one minute to the next, so each time a program needs authentication it prompts you again. Just a guess.